# How do I create a new object using dependency injection

Tags: c#, json, dependency-injection, ninject

At the moment I have a form where users create a new object. This is then passed to the controller as JSON.

How can I create a new object from this JSON to insert into the DB that I have, without doing

```
var x = new CustomObject {
    ExampleField = JSONProperty,
    ExampleField2 = JSONProperty2
};
repo.Create(x);
```

Comment: You should really check AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need something like this:

```
[HttPost]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(string json)
{
    var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json);
    repo.Create(customer);
    return View(customer);
}
```

- An action method that takes as a parameter your json.
- Use the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject method (I have supposed that you use 
  the Newtonsoft.Json library, the most used JSON framework for .NET.
- The customer hew is an hypothetical object. You can follow the same approach for any custom object.
- Last but not least this method return a View. This is optional, you can define another return type and return whatever you want.